# Load Specific URL page in WebView if the Push Notification is Clicked

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am quite a newbie in Android studio and have a question about it.

So I have an android app using Webview. I also implement the FCM push notification. 
When I click the notification, it directly opens the homepage. What if I want to open the specific page in the app when I click the notification?

here is the main activity

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
    private val URL = "https://thelink.pl"
    lateinit var webView: WebView
    private var notificationId: Int = 0;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        webView = createView()
        setContentView(webView)

        firebaseInstanceToken() //get token
        subscibeToTopics("androidUsers")
    }
```

and here is my FCM service

```
 // [START receive_message]
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        //check if message contains a data payload
        remoteMessage
                .data.isNotEmpty().let {
            Log.d("isData", "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.data)
                    theMessageBody = remoteMessage.data.get("body").toString()
                    theMessageTitle = remoteMessage.data.get("title").toString()
                    theMessageDetail_ = remoteMessage.data.get("messageDetail").toString()
                    sendNotification(theMessageBody, theMessageTitle, theMessageDetail_)
        }

        //check if the message contains a notification payload
        remoteMessage
                .notification?.let {
                    theMessageBody = it.body!!
                    theMessageTitle = it.title!!
                    sendNotification(theMessageBody, theMessageTitle, theMessageDetail_)
        }
    }
```

any help is appreciated.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

did you send specific page via FCM? then just send using intent.

in my case,

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Dlog.e("messageBody = " + messageBody);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(messageBody);

            int pushType = jsonBody.getJSONObject("data").getInt("pushType");
            String pushTitle = jsonBody.getString("title");
            String textBody = "";
            String contentText = "";
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;



                String push_title = jsonBody.getString("title");
                String boardContent = jsonBody.getJSONObject("data").getString("boardContent");
                String boardUrl = jsonBody.getJSONObject("data").getString("boardUrl");

                textBody = boardContent;
                contentText = boardContent;

                if (boardUrl.equals("")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                }else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushWebViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("push_title", push_title);
                    intent.putExtra("boardUrl", boardUrl);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                }


            Bitmap icon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
            bigText.bigText(textBody);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("channel", "channel_nm", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{500, 500, 500, 500});
                mChannel.setLightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
                AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .build();
                mChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mChannel.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION), att);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), mChannel.getId());
            } else {
                notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            }
            notificationBuilder
                    .setLargeIcon(icon2)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(pushTitle)
                    .setContentText(contentText)
                    .setStyle(bigText)
                    .setLights(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), 3000, 3000)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{500, 500, 500, 500})
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


            int random_num = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            notificationManager.notify(random_num, notificationBuilder.build());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I get url from FCM and send to page and webView load url

Comment: you mean I should create a new activity ? and redirect the intent to this new activity?

Comment: you can make one Activity. I mean you have to send to Activity for different as before. So in Activity, seperate type for different url.

Comment: so, currently, I have one MainActivity that includes all the configuration. So, now I must create a new activity with different url.. correct ?

Comment: No. you don't need to make other activity (If you don't want). 1. Type for setting up url different from the existing url shall be received as fcm. 2. Override OnResume function In activity. in here you can change url (or change url before webview load).